# Неактивна панель администрирования Jenkins на 8080 порту

Tags: java, jenkins

После из установки Jenkins 2.6 следую простой инструкции из [документации](https://jenkins.io/doc/#guided-tour)

> 1. Download Jenkins.
> 2. Open up a terminal in the download directory and run java -jar
>      jenkins.war
> 3. Browse to http://localhost:8080 and follow the instructions to complete the installation.
> 4. Many Pipeline examples require an installed Docker on the same computer as Jenkins.

и перехожу на `http://localhost:8080`, однако вместо продолжения инсталляции, как об этот написано в инструкции, я получаю страницу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и в некотором замешательстве, куда копать дальше. Win server 2012 R2, Java 8

Comment: а при запуске что-нибудь в консоль писалось?

Comment: добавьте информацию из инструкции в вопрос. ссылка может поменяться и вопрос потеряет ценность.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman да, какие-то исключения валились, потом взял бинарник и установил из него. Проблем не было. Добавил свое решение в качестве ответа, если я неправ, поправьте, пожалуйста

Comment: @MikhailVaysman чем отличает установка через бинарник от установки через `java -jar jenkins.war`

Comment: war файл должен был загрузить кучу файлов из сети, а так же сказать вам пароль. вы видели пароль?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman не видел.сетевые ограничения могут влиять на установку с помощью `.jar`?

Comment: вероятно это из-за занятого порта. по этой причине у вас и не установилось.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Так, вроде решение нашлось. С Вин плотно не работал, могу допустить ошибку, поправьте меня, пожалуйста, если я неправ.

Командой

`netstat -aon`

Увидел, что порт 8080 занят другим процессом, поэтому прошел в файл конфига

`/C/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/jenkins.xml`

И изменил аргумент `--httpPort=8080` на 8081

При обращении на страницу `http://localhost:8081` Jenkins предложил мне продолжить установку